# ES6 Module throwing unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm absolutely blown away that I'm having this issue, but here we go. I'm getting the error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

On this line of code in my index.js file:

```
import { CountUp } from '/js/count-up.js';
```

That line is the first line in the file and my script tags on the HTML page look like this:

```
<script type="module" src='/js/count-up.js'></script>
<script src='index.js'></script>
```

I'm on a Macbook pro running Mojave and I'm in Chrome 73.

I really don't know where I've gone wrong here, **why am I getting an uncaught syntax error on a simple es6 module import?**

Comment: Can you post the content of `count-up.js`? If it's an external library, provide a link to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<script src='index.js'>` is missing the `type="module"` attribute, so it is trying to load it without support for ES6 module syntax (which is needed for `import`).

---

Aside:

Remove:

> ```
> <script type="module" src='/js/count-up.js'></script>
> ```

You only need to load the entry point to your JS program with a `<script>` element. `/js/count-up.js` is loaded using `import { CountUp } from '/js/count-up.js';`.

Comment: It's not a module, that's just a regular script

Comment: @AdamMcGurk — It attempts to `import` a module. It needs support for ES6 modules.

Comment: @AdamMcGurk you need `type=module` to use either `import` or `export`, to be clear

Answer (score -1):

Use the attribute "type" in your script declaration:

https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js/

"Include in your html. Notice the type attribute"

```
<script src="./js/countUp.min.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: @AdamMcGurk doesn't look like that in your snippet